# SimpleMembershipProvider, Entity Framework and default database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, simplemembership

I'm using in a MVC4 internet app the new SimpleMemebership provider with Entity Framework code first. Evrything is fine except that the framework creates the new database with named "DefaultConnection" even if I changed it.

```
<add name="MyDB" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=BeerOperator; Integrated Security=SSPI; MultipleActiveResultSets=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and in Filters\InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute.cs

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("MyDB", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

I really don't understand what I need to change in order to have the User management table created into MyDB database.

Many thanks
davide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found it.
In the AccountModel.cs I had:

```
public UsersContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
```

I changed into:

```
    public UsersContext() : base("MyDB")
```

and now is ok.